# Read a file while another program locked it

Tags: c++, windows, file-locking

I have a program which reads a file written by a software. But the software locks the file while writing to it (I cannot even copy the file!). How can I read the file while it is writing to it?

I'm using Windows 7 with NTFS filesystem, my program is written in C++.

Comment: If you don't have the source and are able to modify the program that's doing the writing, you cannot.  Even if you can do these things (as per @max taldykin's answer) then depending on _why_ you're trying to read a file that's being written to and how it's being written, you may have to be careful about data consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program which writes to the file should open it with read sharing enabled, otherwise other processes can't read from the file that is not closed yet:

> **FILE_SHARE_READ**
>
> Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request read access.
> Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they request read access.
> If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for read access, the function fails.

See more details in [MSDN CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: if this flag is not enabled, is there any way to open it for read? (any trick,hack,...?)

Comment: Don't know about any hacks, but if you have enough privileges you can kill the program that holds a lock and it will release it.